# Set UICollectionViewFlowLayout object attributes directly?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it possible to set `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object attributes directly without touching `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol?

For example, if I want every item size to be the same, could I just do this:

```
self.collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100,100)
```

instead of this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

If positive, how can I reference the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object?

If negative, could you explain why Apple choose to make it a protocol? It obviously requires more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not by accessing an existing UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance. You need to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and handle all of the attributes that you'd like to in your subclass.

There were some great WWDC sessions on that this year, and I recommend watching them. You can see [Session 205 here (login required)](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766) and [Session 219, here(login required)](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.16351493766). The second video will address your question directly.

Comment: The two links don't link to the each session directly. Could you provide session numbers respectively?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the default flow layout from your UICollectionViewController.
For instance, from your viewDidLoad you can call

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)[[self collectionView] collectionViewLayout];
```

and then set the the attributes with:

```
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100.0,100.0)];
```